# How to trigger a double click with Selenium / Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

It's my first time asking. I'm trying to make a double click using ruby but I don't know why I can't do that.

The code is this one (sorry, but I needed to change the code and links due to my job).

Tried to double click on the last code line. I already tried to copy paste the last line 2 and 4 times trying to double click, but does not work.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path="C:/chromedriver.exe"
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
@driver.get 'http://www.google.com’'
sleep 3
@driver.find_element(:id, "Y_UserName").send_keys("pb")
@driver.find_element(:id, "Y_Password").send_keys("pb")
@driver.find_element(:id, "Y_LoginButton").click
sleep 3
@driver.find_element(:id, "MenuID_1").click
sleep 3
@driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucConsultClient_rbCPF").click 
@driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucConsultClient_maskTxtCPF").send_keys("number")
@driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucConsultClient_btnLocalize_input").click
sleep 2
@driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucConsultClient_grdResultClient_ctl00__0").click **#(I tried to double click here)**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use actions to perform a double click.

```
el = @driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucConsultaCliente_grdResultadoCliente_ctl00__0")

@driver.action.double_click(el).perform
```

Comment: Thanks Alec Sanger! Works perfectly! TY!